# Swift Filtering data with collectionview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, filter, collectionview

So im trying to filter my collectionview data using another collectionview, something like this [image]

as from the picture on i try to make a filter button so i can filter the data base on the button that user tap, and the way im trying to make that filter button is to use another collectionview, but i dont know how to implement it.

so far here's my code  :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
if collectionView == homeColView {
  return homeVm.heroList.count
}else if collectionView == filterColView {
  return homeVm.filterRoles.count
  }
return 0
  }

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
if collectionView == homeColView{
  let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "HomeCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeCollectionCell
  let data = homeVm.heroList[indexPath.row]
  let imgUrl = URL(string: BASE_URL + data.img)
  
  cell.heroNameLabel.text = data.localized_name
  cell.heroImage.kf.setImage(with: imgUrl)
  
  return cell
}else if collectionView == filterColView {
  let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "FilterCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! FilterCollectionCell
  
  cell.filterLabel.text = homeVm.filterRoles[indexPath.row]
  return cell
}
return collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "HomeCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeCollectionCell
 }

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

if collectionView == homeColView {
  let vc = HeroDetailsVc()
  vc.heroDetailsVm.heroDetails = homeVm.heroList[indexPath.row]
  
  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
  
  collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: true)
}else if collectionView == filterColView {
  
}
```

}

can anyone help me how to make this filter with collectionview?

Thank you

Comment: What about using only one collection, and just update the array of the character (be it a heroe or a vilain), and then reload the collectionView?

Comment: can you show me some example sir? that would be nice @Larme

Comment: You need another array which contains the filtered hero and that is use for hero collection. You setup this array each time you select a filter and after reload data of hero collection.

Comment: so  you saying i do this "You setup this array each time you select a filter" from the didSelectItemAt, and what i use in numberOfItemsInSection is im using the filtered array not the original array that contain all of the data? @PtitXav

Comment: Yes. So you only have to filter data once.